# Show custom post with custom categories with specific slug

Tags: posts, customization, slug

I'm trying to pull through a custom post with a custom categories and show only a specific slug.

e.g. 
Custom Post (Job Board) - Custom Category (Job Sector) - Specific Slug (Industrial)

What I have show far is;

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job-sector',
            'field' => 'industrial', //can be set to ID
        )
    )
);
```

Yet nothing seems to be showing...can anyone help or suggest where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:
With the post_type the name of your CPT

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'your_cpt_name',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job-sector',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'industrial',
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

$arg = array( 'post_type' => 'custom_post_type_name',

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'Brand',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'Nokia',
    )
)
```

);

$query = new WP_Query( $arg );

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back so promptly! I've tried that and no success. If it helps my `jobs-board` is the custom post. `job-sector` is the custom category I want to target and `industrial` or "8" is the slug?